# Bitwise not in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am learning C and was wondering why does the bit-wise NOT `~` in the following example print -1, :

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int u_n = 0;

int main(void) {
// your code goes here

printf("%d\n", ~u_n);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%d` is for (signed) `int`, use `%u`

Answer (score 4):

By using the `%d` format specifier to `printf`, you're telling it to print the `unsigned int` value as `int`.

Since your machine most likely uses 2's compliment representation for integers, a value with all bits set to 1 is interpreted as -1.

If on the other hand you used the `%u` format specifier, it would print the value as unsigned.  Depending on the size of `int`, this value will be:

- 65535 (16 bit)
- 4294967295 (32 bit)
- 18446744073709551615 (64 bit)